# Работа с сокетами: функция socket_select()

Tags: php, сокет

Не могу разобраться в работе функции socket_select().  У меня есть сокет-клиент который стучится на сервер, шлёт сообщения и читает ответ. Однако дебагер говорит, что ничто не попадает в массив $write. Вот кусок метода, где происходит обработка.

```
if (!$this->socketMaster = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)) {
    error_log('socket_create() failed: ' . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()));
    die();
}
if (!socket_bind($this->socketMaster, $this->address, $this->port)) {
    error_log('socket_bind() failed: ' . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()));
    die();
}
if (!socket_listen($this->socketMaster)) {
    error_log('socket_listen() failed: ' . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()));
    die();
}

//помещаем мастер сокет в массив на чтение

$read = array($this->socketMaster);
$write = array();
$error = array();
$client_sockets = array();
$addressPeer = "";
while (!$this->stop_server) {
$read[] = $this->socketMaster;  
$read = array_merge($read, $client_sockets);

    $num_changed = socket_select($read, $write, $error, 0, 10000);
    //если что-то изменилось
    if ($num_changed) {
        if (in_array($this->socketMaster, $read)) {
            if (count($client_sockets) < $this->max_clients) {
                $socket = socket_accept($this->socketMaster);
                $client_sockets[$addressPeer] = $socket;                
            }

            // Цикл по всем сокетам с проверкой изменений в каждом из них
            foreach ($client_sockets as $addressPeer => $client) {
                //клиентский сокет передаёт данные
                    if (in_array($client, $read)) {
                        //обработка поступающих дыннах
                    }
                    if (in_array($client, $write)) {
                        //отправляем данные
                    }
                    if (in_array($client, $error)) {
                        //обработка ошибок
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В [примере](http://php.su/functions/?socket-select) у socket_select() вообще только 4 аргумента.

Comment: [Их больше][1]


  [1]: http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.socket-select.php

Comment: Это из примера по Вашей же ссылке

    $num_changed_sockets = socket_select($read, $write, $except, 0);

или мне зрение изменяет?

Хотя, возможно лишние не мешают, а просто Вы что-то не то передаете в $write и $except. Попробуйте NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@zenith](/users/5568/zenith), пардон, посмотрел повнимательней и **все очень просто**.

Пятый (необязательный) параметр - это **микросекунды**. Т.е. Вы вызываете селект и он возвращается через 10000 микросекунд (почти сразу). Поэтому и пусто.

Если 4-й параметр 0 (а 5-го нет (или он тоже 0)), то будет бесконечное ожидание.

Вот в этом-то и дело.

Comment: Это в этом случае. В оригинале у меня там стоит 10.

Answer (score 0):

Иногда мне кажеться что я идиот. Надо перепройти iq-тест :(

**По существу:** 
Я не могу точно сказать что именно делает socket_select() с принятыми данными, но вошедшие массивы как правило уменьшаються в размере.
Моя ошибка был в предположении что раз три массивы передаються в функцию по ссылке, то те сокеты которые меняют состояние должны перейти в другой массив(Т.е. если блокируется приём - то в массив на чтение и наоборот).
К концу дня я-таки вкурил что на самом деле socket_select тупо удаляет из массива те сокеты которые не изменили состояния и возвращает кол-во тех которые изменили ( или что-то в этом роде ).
Теперь в начале цикла я объединяю массив со всеми сокетами и массивы состояний:

```
$read[] = $this->socketMaster;
$read=   array_merge($client_sockets,$read);
$write=  array_merge($client_sockets,$write);
$error=  array_merge($client_sockets,$error);
$num_changed = socket_select($read, $write, $error, 0, 10);
```

Ненавижу php. Пойду учить java.

Comment: Но вот обвинять php тут вроде бы не в чём. Это select такой. И как php'шники могли по-другому обернуть select, представить сложно. man 2 select :)

Comment: Кстати, системный вызов `select` тоже модифицирует свои аргументы (битовые маски).

Обычно в цикле опроса перед вызовом `select` аргументы каждый раз строятся "по новой", а после вызова анализируются.